# Getting Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource error while depolye django project with apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf

Here is my error from `error_log`:

```
    \[Fri Mar 22 16:00:09.035343 2024\] \[wsgi:info\] \[pid 63294:tid 63294\] mod_wsgi (pid=63896): Process 'swpdoc' has died, deregister and restart it.
    \[Fri Mar 22 16:00:09.035428 2024\] \[wsgi:info\] \[pid 63294:tid 63294\] mod_wsgi (pid=63896): Process 'swpdoc' terminated by signal 1
    \[Fri Mar 22 16:00:09.035443 2024\] \[wsgi:info\] \[pid 63294:tid 63294\] mod_wsgi (pid=63896): Process 'swpdoc' has been deregistered and will no longer be monitored.
    \[Fri Mar 22 16:00:09.036602 2024\] \[wsgi:info\] \[pid 63897:tid 63897\] mod_wsgi (pid=63897): Starting process 'swpdoc' with uid=48, gid=48 and threads=15.
    \[Fri Mar 22 16:00:09.039512 2024\] \[wsgi:info\] \[pid 63897:tid 63897\] mod_wsgi (pid=63897): Python home /opt/Production/swpdoc/venv311.
    \[Fri Mar 22 16:00:09.039593 2024\] \[wsgi:info\] \[pid 63897:tid 63897\] mod_wsgi (pid=63897): Initializing Python.
```

Python path configuration:

```
 PYTHONHOME = '/opt/Production/swpdoc/venv311'
      PYTHONPATH = (not set)
      program name = 'python3'
      isolated = 0
      environment = 1
      user site = 1
      safe_path = 0
      import site = 1
      is in build tree = 0
      stdlib dir = '/opt/Production/swpdoc/venv311/lib64/python3.11'
      sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
      sys.base_prefix = '/opt/Production/swpdoc/venv311'
      sys.base_exec_prefix = '/opt/Production/swpdoc/venv311'
      sys.platlibdir = 'lib64'
      sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
      sys.prefix = '/opt/Production/swpdoc/venv311'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/opt/Production/swpdoc/venv311'
  sys.path = [
    '/opt/Production/swpdoc/venv311/lib64/python311.zip',
    '/opt/Production/swpdoc/venv311/lib64/python3.11',
    '/opt/Production/swpdoc/venv311/lib64/python3.11/lib-dynload',
  ]
```

Here is my `httpd.conf`

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/Production/swpdoc/techdocsweb/swpdoc/wsgi.py
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

<Directory /opt/Production/swpdoc/techdocsweb/swpdoc>
 <Files wsgi.py>
     Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>
```

LogLevel info
`WSGIVerboseDebugging` On

```
WSGIDaemonProcess swpdoc python-home=/opt/Production/swpdoc/venv311  python-path=/opt/Production/swpdoc/techdocsweb
WSGIProcessGroup swpdoc`
```

I am using `apache` : apache as user and group. Any help will be appriciated.

I already tried giving `chmod -R 755 /opt/Production/swpdoc and chown -R apache:apache /opt/Production/swpdoc`

Comment: It would help to format your post... check https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help